Custom currency formatting in lightning datatable
So I've been struggling with this, I have a lightning datatable which has a currency type column that users can edit, however I need to format the cells of these columns to add text at the end of the value so something like "$20000 per year".
However I am at a loss as to how to even achieve this, can anyone help me with what to do here?

To achieve this functionality, you can use custom data types in the lightning-datatable. A custom data type allows you to format cell values dynamically, including adding additional text like "per year" while still making the cells editable.
Here’s how you can achieve this:

Create a custom type to handle the formatting of the currency column.

Use a customType renderer to append "per year" or any text to the currency value.

Use the editable property on the column and implement logic to handle edits while retaining the custom formatting.


Code:
JavaScript Controller:
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomDatatable extends LightningElement {
@track data = [
    { id: 1, salary: 20000 },
    { id: 2, salary: 30000 },
    { id: 3, salary: 40000 },
];

columns = [
    {
        label: 'Salary',
        fieldName: 'salary',
        type: 'customCurrency',
        editable: true,
        typeAttributes: {
            currencyCode: 'USD', // Optional, specify if needed
            suffix: 'per year',
        },
    },
];

handleSave(event) {
    const draftValues = event.detail.draftValues;

    // Update the data with the new values
    this.data = this.data.map((row) => {
        const draftValue = draftValues.find((draft) => draft.id === row.id);
        return draftValue ? { ...row, ...draftValue } : row;
    });

    // Clear draft values to remove edit indicators
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').draftValues = [];
}
}

HTML Template:
<template>
<lightning-datatable
    key-field="id"
    data={data}
    columns={columns}
    draft-values={draftValues}
    onsave={handleSave}>
</lightning-datatable>
</template>

To support a custom data type (customCurrency), I created a custom renderer named 'customCurrencyRenderer'.
customCurrencyRenderer.js:
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomCurrencyRenderer extends LightningElement {
@api value; // The raw value from the data
@api currencyCode; // e.g., 'USD'
@api suffix; // The text to append, e.g., 'per year'

get formattedValue() {
    const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
        style: 'currency',
        currency: this.currencyCode || 'USD',
    });
    return `${formatter.format(this.value)} ${this.suffix || ''}`;
}
}

customCurrencyRenderer.html:
<template>
<span>{formattedValue}</span>
</template>

customCurrencyRenderer.js-meta.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="customCurrencyRenderer">
<isExposed>true</isExposed>
<targets>
    <target>lightning__datatable</target>
</targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

This will ensure that the column displays "per year" dynamically while allowing users to edit the raw values.
